# ALTER TABLE WITH SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter-table

I need to find all uppercase column names in our databases and alter them to lowercase. However, I'm having troubles making this work. Any help is appreciated

```
ALTER TABLE (SELECT  quote_ident(c.table_schema) || '.'
  || quote_ident(c.table_name) || ' RENAME "' || c.column_name || '" TO ' || quote_ident(lower(c.column_name)) || ';' As ddlsql
  FROM information_schema.columns As c
  WHERE c.table_schema NOT IN('information_schema', 'pg_catalog') 
      AND c.column_name <> lower(c.column_name) 
  ORDER BY c.table_schema, c.table_name, c.column_name;);
```

Comment: You cannot use parameters or subqueries instead of a table name or other identifier. You'll have to write two separate statements.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but if you just remove the quotes from any table names, then it doesn't matter if the table names are CaPiTaliSed Or nOt!

Comment: ...as long as not a reserved word, or no strange characters like <space> or similar are used.

Comment: Will view, triggers, stored procedures etc still work? (I don't know Postgresql, so I'd check this out _before_ doing any changes.) Same for all application code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try this :

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE 
   ddlsql TEXT; 
BEGIN 
   FOR ddlsql IN (
      SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(c.table_schema) || '.'
      || quote_ident(c.table_name) || ' RENAME COLUMN "' || c.column_name || '" TO ' || quote_ident(lower(c.column_name)) || ';' 
      FROM information_schema.columns As c
      WHERE c.table_schema NOT IN('information_schema', 'pg_catalog') 
        AND c.column_name <> lower(c.column_name)
   )
   LOOP
      EXECUTE ddlsql;
   END LOOP;
END $$;
```

It should automatically generate and execute all the necessary ALTER TABLE statements.

Please try and tell

Comment: It worked perfectly!  Thank you!

Comment: Since the above answered your question then kindly accept the answer. This helps future questioners with the same or similar questions and removes the question from the unanswered questions queue. Please do not leave successfully answered questions as unanswered.